# How to make HTTP Server Websocket (WS) connection work on a HTTPS site?

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, tls1.2, nginx-reverse-proxy

My browser game's server doesnt support TLS higher than 1.0 and firefox dropped support for 1.0

So If I get SSL for game server then Firefox players wont be able to play.

I am looking for advice. How to have both HTTPS on site and have HTTP websocket connection (WS) on it?

I heard I can redirect the traffic with NGINX proxy or something like that to make it work but i have no idea about anything like this.